How can I make my vintage sturmey Archer AW hub take a 3 speed cassette? (Minimal metal work, none if possible)
So to make answering my question easier, I'll start with the goals, I wish to be able to attach a 3 speed cassette and tensioner (relatively low cost) to my vintage Sturmey Archer AW hub so i can have more variation in my gears (comfort), the problem comes with needing a solution that doesn't include welding or simply replacing my current hub as I can't unspoke or respoke hubs myself, I can't weld and I don't have tons of cash to buy the old cyclo tensioner, but still that would not solve the problem of attaching a 3 speed cassette to my hub securely.
Tldr: how do I attach a 3 speed cassette and tensioner to my vintage Sturmey Archer 3 speed hub?
If relevant I use a vintage hercules I found at a tip that I restored to working condition, the type is unknown to me.

Not a full answer but rather a comment: the Brompton manufacturer has solved using Sturmey Archer hubs with derailleurs together (and uses a 2-speed derailleur system with a 3-speed hub). It's a completely custom solution, with parts used nowhere else than in Brompton, but it works.

@juhist the 9-spline HG sprocket carrier used by Brompton is available as an aftermarket spare from Sturmey. Furthermore, hubs with the 9-spline carrier are available new (suffix "N")

The part referred to by Juhist MIGHT fit your hub, and would at least allow 2 sprockets.
